# OpenGL debug context warning - "Will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer objection

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, opengl-3

I'm jumping through the hoops right now to learn opengl and I've come across an issue. On my desktop computer with a nvidia gtx 780 opengl is printing out a warning via the glDebugMessageCallback mechanism:

"Buffer object 1 (bound to _GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, usage hint is GL_STATIC_DRAW) will use VIDEO memory as the source for buffer object operations."

I'm rendering 1 cube with a vertex and index buffer so this message repeats for every buffer object I'm creating (2 of them). However, there is also one final warning at the end which states:

"Vertex shader in program 3 is being recompiled based on GL State."

I'm still able to render my cube I was rendering before, but the color I had set is flashing between white and the color now. I searched online and found this answer - https://community.khronos.org/t/nvidia-output-debug-error-131185/66033 - which basically said this is nothing but a warning and everything should be fine but that wouldn't explain why my cube is flashing between white and my color now. This same code is working fine on my laptop (2019 Asus laptop which also has a nvidia GTX graphics chip). Anyone come across this issue before? Here is the relevant code:

```
const char* vertexShaderCode =
R"HereDoc(

#version 430

in layout(location=0) vec3 position;
in layout(location=1) vec3 color;
out vec3 fragColor;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;

void main()
{
vec4 newPos = vec4(position, 1.0) * transformationMatrix;//vector is on the left side because my matrices are row major
gl_Position = newPos;

    vec3 changedColors;
    changedColors.r += color.r + 0;
    changedColors.g += color.g + 0;
    changedColors.b += color.b + 0;
    fragColor = changedColors;
};

)HereDoc";

const char* fragmentShaderCode =
R"HereDoc(

#version 430

out vec4 color;
in vec3 fragColor;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(fragColor, 1.0f);
};

)HereDoc";

void GLAPIENTRY MyOpenGLErrorCallbackFunc(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar *message, const void *userParam)
{
    BGZ_CONSOLE("%s type=0x%x %s\n", ( type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR ? "** GL ERROR **" : "" ), type, message);
};

void CheckCompileStatus(GLuint shaderID)
{
    GLint compileStatus;
    glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &compileStatus);

    if(compileStatus != GL_TRUE)
    {
        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetShaderiv(shaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);

        GLchar buffer[512] = {};
        GLsizei bufferSize;
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, infoLogLength, &bufferSize, buffer);

        BGZ_CONSOLE("%s", buffer);
        InvalidCodePath;
    };
};

void CheckLinkStatus(GLuint programID)
{
    GLint linkStatus;
    glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);

    if(linkStatus != GL_TRUE)
    {
        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetProgramiv(programID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);

        GLchar buffer[512] = {};
        GLsizei bufferSize;
        glGetProgramInfoLog(programID, infoLogLength, &bufferSize, buffer);

        BGZ_CONSOLE("%s", buffer);
        InvalidCodePath;
    };
};

local_func void InstallShaders()
{
    GLuint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    const char* adapter[1];
    adapter[0] = vertexShaderCode;
    glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);
    adapter[0] = fragmentShaderCode;
    glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, 1, adapter, 0);

    glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

    CheckCompileStatus(vertexShaderID);
    CheckCompileStatus(fragmentShaderID);

    GLuint programID = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programID, vertexShaderID);
    glAttachShader(programID, fragmentShaderID);
    glLinkProgram(programID);

    CheckLinkStatus(programID);

    glUseProgram(programID);
};

local_func void
GLInit(int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glDebugMessageCallback(MyOpenGLErrorCallbackFunc, 0);

    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);

    glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);//Defaults to CCW ordering of indicies meaning all indicies that, from the viewers perspective, creating triangles in a CW manner repsrent visible triangles.
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);//Culls only back faces (faces facing away from viewer)
    InstallShaders();
}


void Draw(Memory_Partition* memPart, s32 id, RunTimeArr<s16> meshIndicies)
{
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 2);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (s32)meshIndicies.length, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
};

//This implements a discriminated union for buffering render commands that my game code layer uses.
void RenderViaHardware(Rendering_Info&& renderingInfo, Memory_Partition* platformMemoryPart, int windowWidth, int windowHeight)
{
    local_persist bool glIsInitialized { false };
    if (NOT glIsInitialized)
    {
        GLInit(windowWidth, windowHeight);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glIsInitialized = true;
    };

    u8* currentRenderBufferEntry = renderingInfo.cmdBuffer.baseAddress;
    Camera3D camera3d = renderingInfo.camera3d;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    for (s32 entryNumber = 0; entryNumber < renderingInfo.cmdBuffer.entryCount; ++entryNumber)
    {
        RenderEntry_Header* entryHeader = (RenderEntry_Header*)currentRenderBufferEntry;
        switch (entryHeader->type)
        {
            case EntryType_InitBuffer:{
                RenderEntry_InitBuffer bufferData = *(RenderEntry_InitBuffer*)currentRenderBufferEntry;

                ScopedMemory scope{platformMemoryPart};

                RunTimeArr<GLfloat> verts{};
                InitArr(verts, platformMemoryPart, bufferData.verts.length * 6);
                s32 i{};
                f32 colorR{1.0f}, colorG{}, colorB{};//Im just hard coding color data right now while I'm learning
                for(s32 j{}; j < bufferData.verts.length; ++j)
                {
                    verts.Push(bufferData.verts[j].x);
                    verts.Push(bufferData.verts[j].y);
                    verts.Push(bufferData.verts[j].z);
                    verts.Push(colorR);
                    verts.Push(colorG);
                    verts.Push(colorB);
                };

                u32 vertexArrayID{};
                glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArrayID);
                glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayID);

                GLuint bufferID;
                glGenBuffers(1, &bufferID);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID);
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * verts.length, verts.elements, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
                glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6, 0);
                glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(GLfloat) * 6, (char*)(sizeof(GLfloat)*3));

                GLuint indexBufferID;
                glGenBuffers(1, &indexBufferID);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBufferID);
                glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(s16) * bufferData.indicies.length, bufferData.indicies.elements, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

                currentRenderBufferEntry += sizeof(RenderEntry_InitBuffer);
            }break;

            //...other cases for entries which are irrelevant to problem

            case EntryType_Geometry: {
                ScopedMemory scope{platformMemoryPart};

                RenderEntry_Geometry geometryEntry = *(RenderEntry_Geometry*)currentRenderBufferEntry;

                //camera transform setup
                Mat4x4 xRotMatrix = XRotation(camera3d.rotation.x);
                Mat4x4 yRotMatrix = YRotation(camera3d.rotation.y);
                Mat4x4 zRotMatrix = ZRotation(camera3d.rotation.z);
                Mat4x4 fullRotMatrix = xRotMatrix * yRotMatrix * zRotMatrix;
                v3 xAxis = GetColumn(fullRotMatrix, 0);
                v3 yAxis = GetColumn(fullRotMatrix, 1);
                v3 zAxis = GetColumn(fullRotMatrix, 2);

                //Setup full transform matrix
                Mat4x4 camTransform = ProduceCameraTransformMatrix(xAxis, yAxis, zAxis, camera3d.worldPos);
                Mat4x4 projectionTransform = ProduceProjectionTransformMatrix_UsingFOV(renderingInfo.fov, renderingInfo.aspectRatio, renderingInfo.nearPlane, renderingInfo.farPlane);
                Mat4x4 fullTransformMatrix = projectionTransform * camTransform * geometryEntry.worldTransform;

                //Send transform matrix to vertex shader
                GLint transformMatrixUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(3, "transformationMatrix");
                glUniformMatrix4fv(transformMatrixUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &fullTransformMatrix.elem[0][0]);

                Draw(platformMemoryPart, geometryEntry.id, geometryEntry.indicies);

                currentRenderBufferEntry += sizeof(RenderEntry_Geometry);
            }break;

            InvalidDefaultCase;
        };
    }

    renderingInfo.cmdBuffer.entryCount = 0;
};
```

EDIT:

I figured out the issue with the colors not working which was answered in the comments below. However, I still don't know what these warnings are trying to tell me and if they are anything I should be looking to fix.

Comment: Wow, that was the reason for the color malfunction. Thank you very much. Still unclear about how to get rid of the opengl error though. Can't find much on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You variable `vec3 changedColors;` is uninitialized. Initialize it with `vec3 changedColors = vec3(0);`. The reason why it works on your laptop might be that its graphics driver will initialize it to zero by default, while your other graphics driver won't.

Regarding the warning (not error). It just warns you that your buffer will be put in video memory since you're using `GL_STATIC_DRAW` for your buffer. It's actually more of a log and you can safely ignore it. If you want to get rid of it you have to filter it away in your callback (which you passed to [`glDebugMessageCallback`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDebugMessageCallback.xhtml)). Your callback will have a `severity` parameter that lets you to filter messages with a certain severity.

Or, if you only want to get rid of that specific message, filter on its `id` value.

Here's an example taken from [blog.nobel-joergensen.com](https://blog.nobel-joergensen.com/2013/02/17/debugging-opengl-part-2-using-gldebugmessagecallback/):

```
void APIENTRY openglCallbackFunction(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length, const GLchar* message, const void* userParam)
{
    cout << "---------------------opengl-callback-start------------" << endl;
    cout << "message: "<< message << endl;
    cout << "type: ";
    switch (type) {
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR:
        cout << "ERROR";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR:
        cout << "DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR:
        cout << "UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PORTABILITY:
        cout << "PORTABILITY";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE:
        cout << "PERFORMANCE";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER:
        cout << "OTHER";
        break;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "id: " << id << endl;
    cout << "severity: ";
    switch (severity){
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW:
        cout << "LOW";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM:
        cout << "MEDIUM";
        break;
    case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH:
        cout << "HIGH";
        break;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "---------------------opengl-callback-end--------------" << endl;
}
```